# Guardar múltiples valores de listado en Angular

Tags: html, angular, input, guardar

Dispongo de un listado de tarjetas para guardar datos, cada tarjeta tiene su propio botón de guardar para la información de una única tarjeta, que funciona correctamente con la siguiente función:

```
save(date, quote, footer) {
    this.quoteService.save(
        date,
        quote, 
        footer, 
        this.selectedCourseFilter, 
        this.userData.userCode
   );
}
```

Ahora en HTML, fuera de ese listado, tengo un botón que debe guardar todas las tarjetas que se editen de una sola vez, y no logro de dar con la manera de poder enviar los mismos datos que paso de una vez a ese botón `save-one-button`:

```
<div class="cards-container">
    <div #cardsContent class="card-content" *ngFor="let item of filterData(); let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="card-date">{{ item.date }}</p>
            <input #cardQuote type="text" class="quote-input" [value]="showQuote(item.date)">
            <input #cardFooter type="text" class="footer-input" [value]="showFooter(item.date)">
        </div>

        <button class="save-one-button" (click)="saveOne(item.date, cardQuote.value, cardFooter.value)">GUARDAR UNA</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="save-all-button" (click)="saveAll($event)">GUARDAR TODAS</div>
```

Hace poco que he empezado con Angular y aun no me manejo bien con el, cualquier respuesta será bienvenida. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se debe hacer un cambio en lo siguiente:

```
*ngFor="let item of filterData(); let i = index"
```

El arreglo devuelto por `filterData()` se debe guardar en una variable para poder recuperarlo luego. Quedando así:

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
```

**Componente**

```
export class TestComponent{
    items: any[] = this.filterData();

    saveAll(){
      // guardar el arreglo this.items
    }
}
```

**En la vista**

```
<div class="save-all-button" (click)="saveAll()">GUARDAR TODAS</div>
```

De esa forma al llamar la función `saveAll()` todos los datos se pueden obtener de la variable `this.items`.